# Get full file paths in ProcessWire ServicesPages API

Tags: php, json, rest, processwire

I'm currently building an app using [ProcessWire](https://processwire.com). I'm using the [ServicePages module](http://modules.processwire.com/modules/service-pages/) to expose my data as a REST-like API.

However, all files seem to be outputted like this:

```
reel_poster: {
    basename: "breakdown-2015-poster.jpg",
    description: "",
    tags: "",
    formatted: false,
    modified: 1468541707,
    created: 1468541707
}
```

**How do I get the actual path / URL of the file referenced? I need to get the path in a JS app, so I can't use the PHP API.**

I've also posted [this on their forums](https://processwire.com/talk/topic/1654-pages-web-service-servicepages/?page=5#comment-124044), but it seems like there's not a lot of activity there.

Comment: This seems to be a known issue: https://processwire.com/talk/topic/1654-pages-web-service-servicepages/?page=3#comment-48900. The comment is from 2013, though. *sigh*

Comment: Here it is again, in 2015: https://processwire.com/talk/topic/1654-pages-web-service-servicepages/?page=4#comment-100002. However, the proposed solution is in PHP, which is not an option for me. :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, if I read [this forum post correctly](https://processwire.com/talk/topic/1654-pages-web-service-servicepages/?page=4#comment-100027), the only way to create the URL is by assembling it manually. We need three things to do that:

- The base path for file assets.
- The ID of the page to which the field is attached.
- The image name.

We *know* that the base path for file assets is `/site/assets/files/`. We can then do this, given that we have a `page` object from the API:

```
var basePath = '/site/assets/files/';
var imagePath = basePath + page.id + '/' + page.image_field.basename;
```

<del>This should work. I think.</del> Yes. This is tested and works.